# Query regarding MYSQL Join & Count

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
clients(client_id, client_name)
client_posts(client_id, website_id, category, posted_by)
```

how do i return the following data:

```
CLIENT_ID    CLIENT_NAME            NUM
    1       test client 1           30
    2       test client 2           17
    3       test client 3           8
```

where `NUM` is the number(count) of times the client ID is found in table client_posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT client_id, client_name, count(*) AS NUM
FROM client_posts cp
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = cp.client_id
GROUP BY client_id
```

Comment: how do i show clients with 0 num? the query above gets rid of those clients.

Comment: Of course you don't see them...if count(*) returns 0 it means there are no rows to return!

Comment: is there a way to show all clients? and num as 0 where no posts are found?

Comment: If you do it the other way around and `LEFT JOIN`client_posts to clients instead.

Answer (score 0):

Query :

```
select cl.client_id,cl.client_name,count(cp.client_id) as NUM
 from clients cl 
 left join client_posts cp on (cl.client_id=cp.client_id)
 group by cp.client_id;
```

[Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbd75/1)